# Hibernate Mapping Files - joining 2 tables without defining relationship?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have classes A, B, C.
A and B have one-to-many relationship in tables/database.
B and C have one-to-many relationship.
I want to retrieve the tree A->B->C.
But when I retrieve A by A's-id, I don't want the collection C retrieved under B.
I want only the records of C that are matching a join-condition that I want define. (based off the 2 common columns in B and C).

So for this scenario,
In the hibernate mapping files, I don't want to define a relationship (set or one-to-many) between the 2 tables or the classes B and C. 
Can someone please let me know, if I can achieve this and how can I achieve this in the mapping files. Thx much.

Comment: Did you actually use `@OneToMany` JPA annotation? with that annotation the default fetch is set to `Lazy` which guarantees that associated entities will be "pulled" only when necessary.

Comment: As I was mentioning, due to DB, I am having to define one-to-many in java/hibernate too. also, my requirement is to pull 1/valid record by default all the time, only lazy=false gets that working. But the question is how to get /retrieve only 1/valid out of the many.  Anyways, for now, I am filtering in java for the 1/valid-ones out of the many returned by hibernate. But still, if there's a way to implement join for the one-to-many in DB, so that we can achieve to retrieve only few out of the many due to a join condition, that would be helpful

Comment: Did you consider to use Hibernate Query Language (hql)? it sounds like you need to structure a dedicated query for the above scenario.